Multiple ways of writing DataAnnotations custom validators
I wrote a custom DataAnnotations validator (for client and server):
public class CustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator { /* ... */ }

However the docs show an alternate approach, using three classes:
public class CustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute { /* ... */ }

public class CustomAttributeAdapter : AttributeAdapterBase<CustomAttribute> { /* ... */ }

public class CustomAttributeAdapterProvider : IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider { /* ... */ }

And one must also register the provider during startup:
services.AddSingleton<IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider, CustomAttributeAdapterProvider>();

My simpler way works, and I don't even register it in the container.
Why do the docs show that more complicated approach? Is there some extra feature or behaviour which my way lacks?

Because an IAttributeAdapter can inject content into the html for client side validation, for attributes which don't implement IClientModelValidator. So you can write validation attributes that know nothing about html / javascript to separate these concerns. eg CustomAttribute can exist in an assembly without a dependency on Microsoft.AspNetCore.

@JeremyLakeman Thanks. Yes I finally figured that out... Attributes only accept compile-time constants, but I needed to pass database data into the validator. So I realised that's what all those other classes were for. The encapsulation you mention is also useful.


My simpler way works, and I don't even register it in the container.


Why do the docs show that more complicated approach? Is there some extra feature or behaviour which my way lacks?

From the doc you referenced, it lists the difference of using custom validation attribute that inherits from ValidationAttribute and  IClientModelValidator with using additional AttributeAdapter and ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider:

Create a class that derives from AttributeAdapterBase<TAttribute> and
a class that implements IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider, and
register your attribute and its adapter in DI. This method follows
the single responsibility principle in that server-related and
client-related validation code is in separate classes. The adapter
also has the advantage that since it's registered in DI, other
services in DI are available to it if needed.

Implement IClientModelValidator in your ValidationAttribute class.
This method might be appropriate if the attribute doesn't do any
server-side validation and doesn't need any services from DI.


